# Plain text file visualization web app

Tags: linux, web, visualization, plaintext

I have a project which is generating a bunch of plain text files. 
They are made from the concatenation of several lines generated with a predictible pattern, for example:

```
DATE1 ; MESSAGE1 - DATABASE_NAME1 
DATE2 ; MESSAGE2 - DATABASE_NAME2 
DATE3 ; MESSAGE3 - DATABASE_NAME3
...
```

On linux, I can easily navigate thanks to tools such as `cat, grep, tail, less, ...`. If I want to filter out database 1337, I can easily use `grep -E ".*;.*-.*1337"`, I can combine command with pipes, ..., which is very convenient.

However, this is not very user-friendly for nonprogrammers. They need to install linux, understand regular expressions, ...

So my question is: Does anyone knows a good tool to display such kind of simple textual data in a web browser, with a fancy interface. I would like to encode the structure of each line with regexes (Here, for example: `(\S+) ; (.*) - (\S+)`) and allow users to filter out, search and sort data based on the structure I have encoded. And, if it is possible, having the possibility to highlight patterns would be a must.

I have already looked at tools such as:

- log.io: but it is just for displaying live data, does not work with stored files, and does not structure arbitrary data
- elasticsearch: it seems a very powerful tool but I only want 10% of the features provided, and often works with log feeders, like logstash. Since my files are not standard Syslogs, it looks not to be the right tool.

I also already thought about implementing it myself with Django, but since good programmers are lazy (and good web application development is a hard job), it would be easier for me if someone has already answered this problem in an open source project.

Does anyone have already heard about one? 
Thank you very much

Comment: A nicely written Q, but voting to close because "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. " Good luck.

Comment: I fully understand. This makes sense. I haven't thought about this as of course, it requires more an opinion than a technical answer. But do you know if there is another place in stackoverflow to post it (meta forum or other)? Thank you very much

Comment: try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com, but read the help section for that forum and phrase your Q so it will be on topic there. Good luck.